# How can I assign a reference cell in a function and then return the value in sml

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, ref

So I have a function in sml that takes an integer value and refs it. 
How can I assign a new value to the variable balance and then return that balance? In the Deposit and WithDraw patterns?

```
datatype Message = GetBalance | Deposit of int | WithDraw of int;

fun opening_account init_amt = let val balance = ref init_amt
                in fn GetBalance => !balance
                 | Deposit x => balance = !balance + x
                 | WithDraw x => balance = !balance - x
               end;
```

Answer (score 1):

To update a reference cell, use `:=`. I.e.:

```
balance := !balance + x
```

If you wish to both update the balance, and then return the new value, simply do one after the other with `;`:

```
(balance := !balance + x; !balance)
```